# Analysis of current flow at a component's edge

Tags: current, electromagnetism, current-measurement, magnetics

For one of my projects, I've designed the following component to deliver power to loads/circuits:

[image]

### **Fig.1**

The component in (Fig.1) breaks into 3 parts(a,b,c), my initial analysis of the current flow is shown in the diagram as **(I)**, however, my concern is with the current flow from component **a** to **b**.

[image]

### **Fig.2**

**How does the current flow in that region?** 
[image]

### **Fig.3**

I tried to break down 3 possible current directions on that edge, which one would be most accurate to describe the current's flow?

The reason I am analyzing that segment, is because of the possible magnetic field associated from this component.

What makes sense to me is a magnetic field that literary wraps around the component, however, a field produced by the sub-current (1) in Fig.3 seems unlikely.

**Update:**

- FEA simulation via ANSYS Maxwell:

[image]

**Fig.4**

[image]

**Fig.5**

Comment: The conduction band charges will have a nearly completely uniform distribution in the metal shape. There will be a slight excess at the surface, but otherwise very nearly uniform distribution throughout. All the way to the corners. A very, very small number of charges will "stick" at some corners in order to accelerate the charges around the bends. Like negative-gravity, so to speak. (Charges don't turn without a reason.) Plus the needed charge gradient along its length. Can you now work out the drift velocity implications given the shape? What happens if the current increases a lot?

Comment: I will attempt to. A uniform distribution is what I intentionally thought so as well.However, consider my point of confusion: The driving force for the charges is perpendicular to the sub-current(1) in Fig.3, how can current be driven to that region with no driving force towards the corners? Maybe that's my limitation in understanding current flow.

Comment: There is a very slight charge *gradient* along the length in order to accelerate the charges, as well. You can actually detect this if you set up a high voltage DC supply and a long wire. Use a pith ball. In the center, the pith ball does nothing. But at each end it is attracted and then instantly repelled as it accumulates some of those charges (which are immediately replaced, of course.)

Comment: I think that there is a big missunderstanding in the intepretation of your question about the scale of your geometry. What are the order of magnitude of the involved variables:  nm,um,mm,meters ? Concerning the currents : fA,uA,mA,A,kA ? Do you care about noise under nA ? Personnaly I think that you deal with electrotechnics.

Comment: Andre, the magnitude should be the standard, A and m. What noise?

Comment: Updated the question with simulation results to those interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing you solve with finite element analysis.

Basically, you model the region of interest as a mesh of lots of small parts.  Then each little part follows the laws of physics, but you can make simplifying assumptions, like that the current is uniform over the small volume.  After running enough relaxation iterations, you get the current into and out of the faces of each little element.  From that you find the macro current.

There are a lot of details about doing finite element analysis correctly and efficiently, but those are the basic principles.  Surely there is software out there already that will do most of this for you.

Comment: Yes, I can use Ansys for this.

Comment: The problem with FEM here is that the charges have very long range effects in a conductor. FEM is great for statics and heat flow and the like where the entire system can be solved solely by using fine gained locality. But the reality here also requires effects that bridge well beyond a nearby cell. I'd be curious how to correctly set this up in FEM. (I suspect it can be, but it seems nontrivial.)

Comment: @jonk: No, charges don't have any long-range effects in a normal conductor (not semi-conductor).  Current in equals current out.  No charges build up.  You basically only model voltage, resistivity, and current.  The solution should be the same as for heat flow assuming the outside of the conductor is perfectly insulated.

Comment: It's exactly the same problem as a thermal analysis. The equations are the same.

Comment: Can't agree. If the effects were local, we would have shot noise in wires. We don't. See The Art of Electronics, 2nd edition, 1989, for a discussion on this point.

Comment: Also, Matter & Interactions, 3rd edition, covers some details about the long range effects of just a few charges in corners over many amps of current around a bend. These are long range effects. Any method applied must correctly compute surface charges, gradients, and distributions all on the surface. I suspect it can be done with FEM. Just not the way you suggest. I'm very interested in the detailed setup required to make it yield the right results, quantitatively.

Comment: @Jonk What  chapter or page of "The art of electronics" ? Thanks.

Comment: @andre Writing from phone now. When I can, I'll provide better references. I should be able to find the pages when I get back. The reason I remember them is because they made physical sense and stuck. All physics is local, except at the quantum level, so FEM should work. The problem is in selecting the right view to apply, I think. Which is why things are curious to me. And none of this disagrees with the lack of shot noise in wires being due to long range effects in wires. I think the OP asks an interesting question I'd like to understand and be able to predict, myself.

Comment: @ jonk   Please do pursue this. I need to better understand the concepts also. Thank you.

Comment: @andre See page 432, 2nd edition, "The Art of Electronics," lower half of left column. Sorry it took so long. But... it takes time to remember something you read a long time back.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I've added a note for andre, now. Also, I think it would be instructive to read Chapters 17ff in Matter & Interactions, 3rd edition. One might start with the section on page 685, as a way of wetting one's appetite on the topic, but not as an answer to the question. I wish I could quote the text here as a segue, though. But it's long, needs pictures, and more. So I simply have to wish there was a place for discussing these issues satisfactorily with drawing tools and the like. Oh, well.

Comment: To those still interested, I've simulated the results  and updated my question to contain them, I guess my initial assumption was some-what correct, that $\i_1\$ would have the least amount of current flow.

Comment: @jonk I have (The Art of Electronics) on another tab, could you please reference the chapter/pages relative to the discussion?